# Locked out of Linux VM after using `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add`

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

Just like [this guy](https://serverfault.com/q/907738/72176), I started getting an error message when trying to add ssh keys:

`Supplied fingerprint does not match current metadata fingerprint`

I get this error when I try to add the keys to

- the specific VM instance details (using web interface)
- the shared metadata (using web interface)

I also get `Permission denied (publickey).` no matter if using `username@instance` or `username_mycomp_com@instance` to login. I and all of my colleagues can also no longer use the ssh web login, meaning we have been locked out of our own server!

I can only attribute this to running the `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add` command, which seems to have affected more than it says.

### Other commands that might have affected this issue

#### `gcloud compute ssh`

```
$ gcloud compute ssh dev-mycomp-no
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/carlerik/.ssh/google_compute_engine.
Your public key has been saved in /home/carlerik/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:cicl5t/5mDmIocrkDopK2C6Rf9OvT7FhKAh9GEMPFd8 carlerik@ubuntu
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
| .=.o.           |
| . * . .         |
|. o o . E .      |
| . o   + o       |
| .. . o S .      |
|+.   . +.B . .   |
|.+o .. .oo..o    |
|+o.=o o.. . .=   |
|=..o=o.+o   +..  |
+----[SHA256]-----+
No zone specified. Using zone [europe-west1-b] for instance: [dev-mycomp-no].
WARNING: Using OS Login user [carlerik_mycomp_com] instead of default user [carlerik]
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.7727415340568554709' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
carlerik_mycomp_com@35.195.71.35: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

### `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add`

```
gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  | stack-overflow 
    loginProfile:
      name: '111200762294302015941'
      posixAccounts:
      - accountId: charged-foo-162409
        gid: '438632669'
        homeDirectory: /home/myuser_mycomp_com
        operatingSystemType: LINUX
        primary: true
        uid: '438632669'
        username: myuser_mycomp_com
      sshPublicKeys:
        f7fd01c562d4edb7292eada91dfb2213ef2344f9db605eedc65ac08cea39327e:
          fingerprint: f7fd01c562d4edb7292eada91dfb2213ef2344f9db605eedc65ac08cea39327e
          key: |
            ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCtB10ag2fipH7Cnls3gZvl5eBJx0OvQaLu7hndL5sif3m4CTGmrN/MuP0lei0Rt23cBy5Ey2DqAjmizCAhdc3jSQm0pXisKG92Juo2HxiJw+eMUucoPhjbEy35sKKrru2//5uPpK5IEeVEve3bIXCAQUQgyOESmHBgXmKSCz0jQXEvcV8GxxkdXK7/UQVSe5wtxzPHOoP+foobar+bjHXnQkiqk5oDeP3ewPorrvxbOeOcqk0b1qrAQYSXHqXv6lENfWIceIz1EsZlRsIV i9-mycomp
```

#### `gcloud compute instances add-metadata the-instance --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE`

Saw this in a guide. Assumed this would enable *additional* ways of logging in. In hindsight, I see I have no idea what this does.

### Debugging info

```
$ gcloud compute os-login describe-profile  
    name: '111200762294302015941'
    posixAccounts:
    - gid: '726506529'
      homeDirectory: /home/myuser_mycomp_com
      operatingSystemType: LINUX
      primary: true
      uid: '726506529'
      username: myuser_mycomp_com
    - accountId: foo-mission-162409
      gid: '438632669'
      homeDirectory: /home/myuser_mycomp_com
      operatingSystemType: LINUX
      primary: true
      uid: '438632669'
      username: myuser_mycomp_com
    sshPublicKeys:
      3573aef91758f9706a884bffc95502ea5f31bbfab7a33d58be8abd9a84f53808:
        fingerprint: 3573aef91758f9706a884bffc95502ea5f31bbfab7a33d58be8abd9a84f53808
        key: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDCaISFI0hCDMK5SIqIBlsboBQTBCoW98bvjUjoCDn9S4kXSOtVvwNeXc/Kb+9lXqKR8CbtYgOZySPqI+5VADdAIcfot2S65Fq5qOQ1IH7Uo29nzvhyjfRbckAs3gaTF6uzxEA0THqyAZ1oGIyK3vDI8W/Ofczi08oIYWpMmWA8dQNQuKRujloDuFElpjZEjbEyfkn/e7iSm1VxZ8aLEw7M3/BsJLmtwxa+tYyTAfKx63NRFbSWf873GLOyAKCnE5ls27ftlTjDJMISI3RZd1KMdyg+6KAwN7YsCTwJXarNXr9v2GcY8lrpC7dQ/lGK1nBsPa0kOSYKQzJ0LIDxfOan
          myuser@ubuntu
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to log in again after disabling os-login:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata dev-diffia-no --metadata enable-oslogin=FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with OS Login enabled and my key being rejected with an old debian jessie instance.

Symptoms where:

- `Permission denied (publickey)` error message on the command line following the `Using OS Login user` message,
- `Received malformed response from server` error message in the `nss_oslogin` module logs.

The resolution was to update the following packages from the proper repository:

- google-compute-engine
- google-compute-engine-oslogin
- python-google-compute-engine
- python3-google-compute-engine

Before:

```
# dpkg -l | grep google
ii  google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring 1.2-1                            all          Contains GPG signing key for Google Cloud Packages
ii  google-cloud-sdk                      253.0.0-0                        all          Utilities for the Google Cloud Platform
ii  google-compute-engine                 2.5.2-4                          all          google-compute-engine transitional package
ii  google-compute-engine-init-jessie     2.1.3-0.1503598199               amd64        Google Compute Engine Linux initialization scripts
ii  google-compute-engine-jessie          2.5.2-0.1502923259               all          Google Compute Engine
ii  google-compute-engine-oslogin         1.0.2-1+deb8                     amd64        Google Compute Engine OS Login
ii  google-config-jessie                  2.1.2-0.1484936429               amd64        Google Compute Engine Linux guest configuration
```

After:

```
# dpkg -l | grep google
ii  google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring 1.2-1                            all          Contains GPG signing key for Google Cloud Packages
ii  google-cloud-sdk                      253.0.0-0                        all          Utilities for the Google Cloud Platform
ii  google-compute-engine                 2.8.16-1                         all          Google Compute Engine guest environment.
ii  google-compute-engine-oslogin         1.4.3-1+deb8                     amd64        Google Compute Engine OS Login
rc  google-config-jessie                  2.1.2-0.1484936429               amd64        Google Compute Engine Linux guest configuration
ii  python-google-compute-engine          2.8.16-1                         all          Google Compute Engine python library for Python 2.x.
ii  python3-google-compute-engine         2.8.16-1                         all          Google Compute Engine python library for Python 3.x.
```

In order to connect to this instance to perform the updates, you need to temporarily disable OS Login by setting `enable-oslogin=FALSE` to the instance's metadata [as described in @oligofren's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/956664/291412).

Then ensure this is present in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud.list` (there may be other lines):

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-jessie-stable main
```

And perform the updates:

```
# sudo apt install --reinstall google-compute-engine google-compute-engine-oslogin python-google-compute-engine python3-google-compute-engine
```

You can then re-enable OS Login for the instance.